# Windows 8.1 App's package report generation error

Tags: xml, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit, appxmanifest

Windows App Certification Kit is throwing error and being closed by self without generating the report for created package App_x.x.x.x_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload for windows store.

The error popup message is
     An error occured while generating report.
     Application will exit.

Once clicked on OK button Windows App Certification is being closed.

The details for error in C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit\TempReport.xml is like that

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<REPORT xml:lang="en-US" OVERALL_RESULT="FAIL" VERSION="10.0.14393.33" LATEST_VERSION="TRUE" UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_URL="" TOOLSET_ARCHITECTURE="x64" SecureBoot="FALSE" APP_TYPE="WindowsStore" PUBLISHER_DISPLAY_NAME="CN=AA091C1F-4CAF-4D2E-A57B-8BECDE2AFBBE" OSVERSION="10.0.14393.0" OS="Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language" PER_USER_APPLICATION="" PARTIAL_RUN="FALSE" LCID="1033">
  <REQUIREMENTS>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="10" TITLE="Deployment and launch tests" RATIONALE="Application failures such as crashes and hangs are a major disruption to users and cause frustration. Eliminating such failures improves application stability and reliability, and overall, provides users with a better application experience.">
      <TEST INDEX="50" NAME="Bytecode generation" DESCRIPTION="Byte code generation should be able to complete successfully for packages containing an HTML5 Windows Store app." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.95ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BytecodeGenerationCheck.BytecodeGenerationCheck.ExecuteSharedValidation(String manifestFilePath, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="47" NAME="App launch" DESCRIPTION="App launch tests." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:20s.75ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="The manifest file for this appx package could not be found." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="60" NAME="Optimized binding references" DESCRIPTION="When using bindings, WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences should be set to true to optimize the memory usage." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.91ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.OptimizeBindingReferencesCheck.OptimizeBindingReferencesCheck.Test(StoreApp storeApp)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="21" NAME="Crashes and hangs" DESCRIPTION="Do not crash or hang during the testing process." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:01s.95ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.WindowsErrorReporting.WindowsErrorReporting.ExecutePostTest(TaskData taskData)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.WindowsErrorReporting.WindowsErrorReporting.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="12" TITLE="Package compliance test" RATIONALE="The package manifest was missing one or more required attributes.">
      <TEST INDEX="77" NAME="Application count" DESCRIPTION="One package should not define more than one app in the manifest." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.98ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.ApplicationCount.ApplicationCount.ExecuteSharedTests(EnumApplicationType appType, String manifestFilePath)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="31" NAME="App manifest" DESCRIPTION="App manifest must include valid entries for all required fields." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.99ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="The manifest file for this appx package could not be found." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="75" NAME="Package size" DESCRIPTION="Package file size should not be greater than 4 gigabytes." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:01s.17ms">
        <MESSAGES />
        <RESULT><![CDATA[PASS]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="14" TITLE="Windows security features test" RATIONALE="Applications must opt-into Windows security features.">
      <TEST INDEX="33" NAME="Binary analyzer" DESCRIPTION="Analysis of security features enabled on binaries" EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.84ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.&#xD;&#xA;   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Msec.Binscope.ExecuteSharedTestsForStoreAndPhone(String manifestFilePath)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="70" NAME="Banned file analyzer" DESCRIPTION="Analysis of application to detect known insecure files" EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.80ms">
        <MESSAGES />
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="62" NAME="Private code signing" DESCRIPTION="App should not package private code signing key files." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.99ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="The manifest file for this appx package could not be found." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="15" TITLE="Supported API test" RATIONALE="The application should only refer to the APIs allowed by the Windows SDK for Windows Store Apps.">
      <TEST INDEX="38" NAME="Supported APIs" DESCRIPTION="Windows Store App must only use supported platform APIs." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.91ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.SupportedApis.SupportedApis.ExecuteSharedTests(EnumApplicationType appType, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="19" TITLE="App manifest resources tests" RATIONALE="The App Package Manifest should have valid resources defined in the resources.pri file, as per the App Packaging Specification and App Manifest Schema.">
      <TEST INDEX="45" NAME="App resources" DESCRIPTION="The package should have valid resources defined in the resources.pri file." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.69ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="The test was blocked from execution. Please try re-running the validation. If the test execution remains blocked then please contact support." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
      <TEST INDEX="61" NAME="Branding" DESCRIPTION="App should not use the default images packed by windows SDK samples or Visual Studio." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.95ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="The manifest file for this appx package could not be found." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="20" TITLE="Debug configuration test" RATIONALE="The App should not install any debug binaries.">
      <TEST INDEX="46" NAME="Debug configuration" DESCRIPTION="The App should not install any debug binaries." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:01s.12ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="Failed to extract imported API information for this application." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
    <REQUIREMENT NUMBER="21" TITLE="File encoding test" RATIONALE="Packages containing an HTML5 Windows Store app must have correct file encoding.">
      <TEST INDEX="49" NAME="UTF-8 file encoding" DESCRIPTION="Packages containing an HTML5 Windows Store app must have correct file encoding." EXECUTIONTIME="00h:00m:00s.97ms">
        <MESSAGES>
          <MESSAGE TEXT="System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.&#xD;&#xA;Parameter name: url&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Shared.AppxProgramInventoryHelper.GetPackageFromManifestFile(String appxManifestFile, Boolean onlyHighLevelDetails, String packageFullName)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.FileEncodingCheck.FileEncodingCheck.ExecuteSharedTests(String packageFullName, String manifestFilePath)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()" />
          <MESSAGE TEXT="[HRESULT 0x80131604] Test operation failed: 'ExecuteTest'." />
        </MESSAGES>
        <RESULT><![CDATA[FAIL]]></RESULT>
      </TEST>
    </REQUIREMENT>
```

Comment: Does the error persist if you package a new empty Windows 8.1 project and run WACK? What is your OS version?

Comment: Do you have the latest windows 10 sdk installed?

Comment: @Mattew, Yeah error is persisting for empty 8.1 project. I guess some setting has changed or else, Because earlier it was working fine as i had created 5 to 6 version of same project.

Comment: Experiencing the same error, failing on 19.